# UnhandledPromiseRejection error when mocking Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, jest-mock-axios

I've got a basic component which submits a form. This is the segments where the form submission is declared:

```
<form id="register" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

and the function that handles the data is:

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
        
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost", data)
             .then( (response) => {
                 console.log(response);
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error);
             });
        
    }
```

In my test I've declared the mock and the test looks like:

```
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock('axios', () => {
    post: () => Promise.resolve({data: []})
})

it('should save value when submitted', async () => {
            
            render(
                <Register />
            );

            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(field('email'), {
                target: { value: 'test@mail.com', name: 'email'}
            })

            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(field('first-name'), {
                target: { value: 'test', name: 'first-name'}
            })

            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(field('last-name'), {
                target: { value: 'test', name: 'last-name'}
            })

            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(field('password'), {
                target: { value: 'test', name: 'password'}
            })

            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(field('confirm-password'), {
                target: { value: 'test', name: 'confirm-password'}
            })


            ReactTestUtils.Simulate.submit(form('register'));


            expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            

        });
```

**Note:** `field` and `form` are simply helpers that get me any field and the form. They work fine, they've been used in other tests.

After running the test I'm getting the following error:

> RUNS  test/Register.test.js node:internal/process/promises:245
> triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
> ^
>
> [UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with
> the reason "TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined".] {
> code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION' }

What's going on here? am I not handling the rejection in the `catch` statement?

Comment: try adding the port as well bro "http://localhost"  "http://localhost:PORTNUMBER"

Comment: That’s a dummy url, it shouldn’t matter as it’ll never really be called from the test. That’s the whole point for using mocks